# Нет перевода "Questions tagged" в вопросах по метке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, описание-метки

Не переведена фраза Questions tagged в вопросах по метке. [Пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5):

> [image: скриншот]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строка в трансе: `568dbca7004f47b6f109caeac64b7e0f`.

Предложил перевод:

> Вопросы с меткой [x]